# How to create a ODBC connection to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I try to use Access to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. But have trouble to build the 
ODBC connection, I do not know am I missing something? Or just need do some set in sql site?

I have a screen like this:

[image]

and code behind the OK button is this:

```
      Dim dbPUBS As dao.Database
      Dim tdfPUBS As dao.TableDef
      Dim qdfPUBS As dao.QueryDef
      Dim strMsg As String
      Dim strSQL As String

  ' Check for existence of Server, Database and User Name.
          ' If missing, inform user and exit.

             If IsNull(Me!txtServer) Then
        strMsg = "Enter name of your company's Server." & _
            & "(See your database administrator)"
        MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation, "Missing Data"
        Me!txtServer.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me!txtDatabase) Then
        strMsg = "Enter name of database. (Example: xxxx)"
        MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation, "Missing Data"
        Me!txtDatabase.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me!txtUID) Then
        strMsg = "Enter user login.  (Example: xx)" = ""
        MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation, "Missing Data"
        Me!txtDatabase.SetFocus
    Else
        strServer   = Me!txtServer
        strDatabase = Me!txtDatabase
        strUID      = Me!txtUID
        ' Password may be NULL, so provide for that possibility
        strPWD      = Nz(Me!txtPWD, "")

        ' Prepare connection string
        strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server}" _
                & ";SERVER=" & strServer _
                & ";DATABASE=" & strDatabase _
                & ";UID=" & strUID _
                & ";PWD=" & strPWD & ";"
    End If


            Private Function ValidateConnectString() As Boolean
           On Error Resume Next

            Err.Clear
            DoCmd.Hourglass True

       ' Assume success

       ValidateConnectString = True

' Create test Query and set properties

        Set qdfPUBS = dbPUBS.CreateQueryDef("")
         qdfPUBS.Connect = strConnect
        qdfPUBS.ReturnsRecords = False
        qdfPUBS.ODBCTimeout = 5

' Attempt to delete a record that doesn't exist

          qdfPUBS.SQL = "DELETE FROM Authors WHERE au_lname = 'Lesandrini'"

' Simply test one Pass Through query to see that previous
' connect string is still valid (server has not changed)

           qdfPUBS.Execute

' If there was an error, connection failed

          If Err.Number Then ValidateConnectString = False

          Set qdfPUBS = Nothing
          DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Function
```

Comment: You could have just used Google for a second. That would have brought up this: http://www.sqlstrings.com/SQL-Server-connection-strings.htm

Comment: Thanks, My connection string is set.Butj it does not work. I just confusing. sorry

Comment: But your connection string seems wrong according to the page I've quoted... For example, it should not say `DRIVER={SQL SERVER}` but `DRIVER={SQLServer}`!

Answer (score 2):

You should pay a visit to [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver) site for details, however, I wouldn't use ODBC if I were you.
My connection is (for SQL Server 2012):

```
Private oCon As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub InitConnection(ByRef sDataSource As String, ByRef sDBName As String)
Dim sConStr As String

    Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
    sConStr = "Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=SQLNCLI11;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & _
               sDataSource & ";Initial Catalog=" & sDBName
    On Error Resume Next
        Call oCon.Open(sConStr)
        If (Err.Number = 0) Then
            'all OK
        Else
            'Show Error Message / Throw / Sink / etc
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Where `sDataSource` is "[COMPUTERNAME]\[SQL SERVER INSTANCE]" (same as in e.g. SSMS, it's like "MyHomePC\SQLEXP") and `sDBName` is the default catalog, ie default DB to open. You'll need to add reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects` so you can use `ADODB` `Connection`, `Command` and `Recordset` objects (in Access VB window: "Tools" --> "References...").
`MSDataShape` is not mandatory but comes handy for hierarchical grids.
EDIT: BTW, from connstr. site: `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` (again, for SQL Server 2012, for 2008 it's "...Client 10.")

Comment: Thank you very much. For a beginer maybe this project just so difficult to me. I will read the link you give to me and see how far can i go.

Comment: You're welcome! Everything is easy - if you know how. You just have to learn into it, that's all ;)

Comment: I see my Sever is 'SQL server 9.0.5000' Does it means Server 2005? and Client 9?

Comment: It's 2005. Your ODBC driver then comes to "Driver={SQL Native Client}"

Comment: Thank you so much. What i want to do is I have Stored Procedure in sql which has four parameter. I want to bulid a application in access let the user execute the store procudure. I find a example online and want to learn how to bulid my own.

Comment: You can do that by ADODB.Command. Either by creating Parameter objects and feed it then call Execute, or simply setting it's CommandText property to the desired SQL statement and then call Execute([SQL String]). SQL is the same with a Stored Procedure as a simple SELECT, e.g. sSQL = "myDB.myUser.SPName 'value1', 'value2'" SET objRecordset = objADODBCommand.Execute(sSQL)

Comment: When starting new projects, note that both [MSDataShape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676105(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as [SQLNCLI11](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/09/04/rip-ole-db.aspx) are officially deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
    strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server}" _
            & ";SERVER=" & strServer _
            & ";DATABASE=" & strDatabase _
            & ";UID=" & strUID _
            & ";PWD=" & strPWD & ";"
```

It should read

```
    strConnect = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}" _
            & ";SERVER=" & strServer _
            & ";DATABASE=" & strDatabase _
            & ";UID=" & strUID _
            & ";PWD=" & strPWD & ";"
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry connection still failed

Comment: I've edited my answer. This is to connect with SQL Server 2008. Please visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for more details.